# Amazon eBook Self-Publishing vs Major Publishing Houses

Tags: amazon, independent-publishing

Quick question for anyone who has some insight... Do the major publishing houses have a different process for publishing ebooks through Amazon than "independent" publishers? I get the feeling that, yes, the big boys have access to more tools than the smaller houses do, but I just wanted to confirm.

Comment: I don't think so, since from the point of view of Bezos each book sold is some earning more and ebooks do not need a lot of interaction, but I may be dead wrong.

Comment: Which tools do you refer? For an individual publisher, Amazon and alike is definitely sub-optimal if he tries to conduct any market research etc. However big publishers has many other channels of information, so you may see them using data from offline sources, surveys or independent market research.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Big publishers may have a more direct route they can take for submitting their titles, but they are still required to follow the same formatting guidelines and provide the same information that Amazon requires of any self-published authors who use their Kindle Direct Publishing (KDP) program. The KDP program provides an interface that authors can use to submit and manage their titles to Amazon for sale as e-books. Basically, this interface is how the author (or publisher) provides all of the pertinent information for the book, and regardless of who is submitting it, that information has to be provided. I think the only real advantage a major publishing house would have would be in their ability to hire a staff that manually enters this information for each book.

Comment: I added this question months ago, but I did do some research  into it and if memory serves me correctly... there was a different "publishing portal" (for lack of a better word) for known publishers. But like you said, the overall process and formatting guidelines for getting a manuscript into ebook form is essentially the same. Thanks!